Why does my Spring Integration app just shutdown without listening?
I am trying to implement a Spring Integration app that listens to websocket messages from an external source and logs them to stdout. However as soon as I start my application it shuts down again, if I don't force it to keep running with a Scanner that waits for the user to enter the letter "q". What is the canonical way to keep the app listening?
This is my code:
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.websocket.ClientWebSocketContainer;
import org.springframework.integration.websocket.inbound.WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
public class BinanceListenerApplication {

    @Bean
    MessageChannel rawAggTradeChannel(){
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow logging(){
        return IntegrationFlow.from(rawAggTradeChannel()).handle(new LoggingHandler(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO)).get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow binanceWebsocketAggTradeStream() {
        var clientWebSocketContainer = new ClientWebSocketContainer(new StandardWebSocketClient(),
                "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/avaxusdt@aggTrade");
        var websocketInboundChannelAdapter = new WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter(clientWebSocketContainer);
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(websocketInboundChannelAdapter)
                .channel(rawAggTradeChannel())
                .get();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BinanceListenerApplication.class);
        context.registerShutdownHook();

        // Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // System.out.print("Please enter q and press <enter> to exit the program: ");

        // while (true) {
        //  String input = scanner.nextLine();
        //  if ("q".equals(input.trim())) {
        //      break;
        //  }
        // }
        // scanner.close();
        // context.close();
        // System.exit(0);

        // SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(BinanceListenerApplication.class);
        // application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        // application.run(args);
    }

}

I would expect the app to keep listening based on this code, as I thought that the WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter should be a message-driven adapter.

main method finished and therefore the program shutsdown. You should start it with SpringApplication.run, in your case SpringApplication.run(BinanceListenerApplication.class, args);

It also shuts down immediately when I use the commented out SpringApplication code. I tried it with SpringApplication.run() and it seems to work. What is the difference between creating an application object and calling the run function and using SpringApplication.run()? Is it because the WebApplicationType is not set to None? Because I certainly see that there is a servlet running with your proposed solution, which I do not need.

@d.oelert hmm SpringApplication also creates non daemon thread which keeps application alive. Application will be alive as long as non daemon threads are running. Looking at your code everything is running in main thread and it closes as main function is executed.

Since you are not interested in the servlet container (or any other HTTP server), it is normal that your application shouts down without any scheduling.
See this property: spring.main.keep-alive=true.
There is not too much docs on the matter, but here is something: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/spring-application.html#features.spring-application.virtual-threads

That worked! I really would have thought that other people might run into similar things with Spring Integration, strange that the documentation is this sparse.

Yeah... This has nothing to do with Spring Integration: just typical Java behavior when you don't use long-lived non-daemon threads. We will think about making Spring Integration as keep-alive by itself when message-driver channel adapters are in use. Similar to what you have so far with WebSocket client.

I'd be happy to contribute, if you were willing to roughly describe the necessary changes.

Sure! Let's create an issue first: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues! From there we definitely would need to discuss what and how. Thanks
